# Sound analysis for fault detection

Tags: python-3.x, signal-processing, svm, feature-selection, mfcc

I am trying to do fault detection of a machine with sound analysis using python.

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
import numpy as np
import speechpy
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
os.chdir('D:\Python\Sound Data')
file_name = 'good8Hz.wav'
Checking_file = 'fault8Hz.wav'

fs, signal = wav.read(file_name)
signal = signal[:,0]
#this is my testing data
fs1, signal1 = wav.read(Checking_file)
signal1 = signal1[:,0]

# pre-emphasizing.
signal_preemphasized = speechpy.processing.preemphasis(signal, cof=0.98)

#pre-emphasizing of testing data .
signal_preemphasized1 = speechpy.processing.preemphasis(signal1, cof=0.98)

#staching frames
frames = speechpy.processing.stack_frames(signal, sampling_frequency=fs, 
frame_length=0.020, frame_stride=0.01, filter=lambda x: np.ones((x,)),
     zero_padding=True)

# staching frames of testing data .
frames1 = speechpy.processing.stack_frames(signal1, sampling_frequency=fs, 
frame_length=0.020, frame_stride=0.01, filter=lambda x: np.ones((x,)),
     zero_padding=True)

#extracting power spectrum 
power_spectrum = speechpy.processing.power_spectrum(frames, fft_points=512)
print('power spectrum shape=', power_spectrum.shape)

#extracting power spectrum for testing data .
power_spectrum1 = speechpy.processing.power_spectrum(frames1, 
fft_points=512)
print('power spectrum shape=', power_spectrum1.shape)

############# Extract MFCC features #############
mfcc = speechpy.feature.mfcc(signal, sampling_frequency=fs, 
frame_length=0.020, frame_stride=0.01,
         num_filters=40, fft_length=512, low_frequency=0, 
high_frequency=None)
mfcc_cmvn = 
    speechpy.processing.cmvnw(mfcc,win_size=301,variance_normalization=True)
print('mfcc(mean + variance normalized) feature shape=', mfcc_cmvn.shape)

mfcc_feature_cube = speechpy.feature.extract_derivative_feature(mfcc)
print('mfcc feature cube shape=', mfcc_feature_cube.shape)

df=pd.DataFrame(mfcc)
df.to_csv('mfcc.csv')
############# Extract MFCC features for testing data . #############
mfcc1 = speechpy.feature.mfcc(signal1, sampling_frequency=fs, 
frame_length=0.020, frame_stride=0.01,
         num_filters=40, fft_length=512, low_frequency=0, 
high_frequency=None)
mfcc_cmvn1 = 
speechpy.processing.cmvnw(mfcc1,win_size=301,variance_normalization=True)
print('mfcc(mean + variance normalized) feature shape=', mfcc_cmvn.shape)

mfcc_feature_cube1 = speechpy.feature.extract_derivative_feature(mfcc1)
print('mfcc feature cube shape=', mfcc_feature_cube1.shape)

df1=pd.DataFrame(mfcc1)
df1.to_csv('mfcc1.csv')
############# Extract logenergy features #############
logenergy = speechpy.feature.lmfe(signal, sampling_frequency=fs, 
frame_length=0.020, frame_stride=0.01,
         num_filters=40, fft_length=512, low_frequency=0, 
high_frequency=None)
logenergy_feature_cube = 
                      speechpy.feature.extract_derivative_feature(logenergy)
 print('logenergy features=', logenergy.shape)
```

How to use mfcc data to train my model I am thinking of useing SVM or ANN.

mfcc.shape =(1118,13) it is good machine mfcc feature and mfcc1.shape=(1278,13)][[screenshot of data]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzWCQ.png) this is mffc of fault machine. What else do I need to use for fault detection of a machine?

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367) and [edit] your post. We need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: MFCC is tailored for speech. You should probably use mel-spectrogram instead. In combination with a RandomForest, GBM or CNN it will usually give better performance on general sound tasks. And visualizes much better, being a spetrogram (x=time, y=frequency)

Comment: To apply machine learning you should have 100 samples per class or more. What is the shortest time that you (as a human) can detect a faulty versus not-faulty machine on? You should split your recordings to be maybe 2-6x that length.

Comment: Thanks for your's valuable comments. 
I used ANN model after extracting the mfcc and got 80% accuracy :).